# Storage problem using Sharedpreferences on Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I created a list using recyclerView. Each list item has a button and a progress bar, and pressing the button increases the value of the progress bar. Also, with SharedPreferences, records are kept even after shutdown.
However, all progress bars store the same value. I want to save the value of the progress bar differently for each button.

This is Adapter code

```
public class DayListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DayListAdapter.MainViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AddDayInfo> mDataset;
    private Activity activity;
    static int nowValue ;

class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cardView;
        ProgressBar daybar;
        Button dayeat;

        MainViewHolder(CardView v) {
            super(v);
            cardView = v;

            this.daybar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.daybar);
            this.dayeat = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dayeat);

            dayeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    saveData();
                    getData();
                    Log.d("addvalue ", String.valueOf(nowValue));

                    //nowValue = bar.getProgress();
                    int maxValue = daybar.getMax(); 

                    if (maxValue == nowValue) {
                        nowValue = 0;
                    } else {
                        daybar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        nowValue += 1;

                    }

                    if (nowValue == 0) {
                        daybar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else
                        daybar.setProgress(nowValue);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    /*Save Data*/
    public void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sf =this.activity.getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
        editor.putInt("KEY2", nowValue);
        Log.e("setv", String.valueOf(nowValue));
        editor.apply();
    }
    /*Get Data*/
    public void getData(){
        SharedPreferences sf =this.activity.getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int value = sf.getInt("KEY2", nowValue);
        Log.e("getv", String.valueOf(value));
        nowValue=value;
    }
```

Comment: Use the position parameter of the item clicked. You should have someting like saveData(position, daybar.Position); and daybar.Position=getData(position);. In your functions: key = "KEY" + position; Using a database is overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you save your value in the same key "KEY2" in sharedPreferences. So, if you need store value of each item you show write in different key. This way is not recommend.
I think you should use local database to store your values, use can use Room: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Eventually I have to use a room,,. I'll study and try again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Room persistent library to store values in Sqlite db.

Refer here :- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0